# Element is not clickable(x,y) even there is no scroll in page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation

I am unable to click on the "Login" button provided in the header I am new to selenium, here is the code snippet

```
public class Muft_Mashwara_login {

    public WebDriver driver= null;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void startBrowser (){

        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://sqa.muftmashwara.be.vteamslabs.com/home");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }   
    @Test
    public void Click()throws InterruptedException 
    {
        //Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header2']/nav/div/ul/li/a")).click();
        WebElement loginTxt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/main/div/section/article[2]/div/div/form[1]/div[1]/div/input"));
        loginTxt.sendKeys("test@test.com");
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void  Close(){
        driver.close();
    }
    }
```

it only works if I un-comment "Thread.sleep" I don't know how to implement dynamic wait in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement *dynamic wait*, try this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header2']/nav/div/ul/li/a"))).click();
```

instead of this:

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header2']/nav/div/ul/li/a")).click();
```